# Getting JRuby-internal Java object from Ruby code

Tags: jruby

I'm wondering if I could get JRuby-internal Java objects (e.g. `org.jruby.RubyString`, `org.jruby.RubyTime`) in Ruby code, and call their Java methods from Ruby. Does anyone know how to do it?

```
str = "foobar"
rubystring_str = str.toSomethingConversion  # <== What I want

# http://jruby.org/apidocs/org/jruby/RubyString.html#getEncoding()
rubystring_str.getEncoding()  # Java::org.jcodings.Encoding
# http://jruby.org/apidocs/org/jruby/RubyString.html#getBytes()
rubystring_str.getBytes()  # [Java::byte]

time = Time.now
rubytime_time = time.toSomethingConversion  # <== What I want
# http://jruby.org/apidocs/org/jruby/RubyTime.html#getDateTime()
rubytime_time.getDateTime()  # Java::org.joda.time.DateTime
```

I know I can do like that using Java code as below, but here, I'd like to do it purely in Ruby.

```
public org.joda.time.DateTime getJodaDateTime(RubyTime rubytime) {
    return rubytime.getDateTime();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I found the answer in my tries-and-errors.

The following works.

```
"foobar".to_java(Java::org.jruby.RubyString).getEncoding()
Time.now.to_java(Java::org.jruby.RubyTime).getDateTime()
```